# Why is this code not throwing a nullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The code snippets are below.

I understand that the default value for a String is `null` and this is assigned to `str`. What I don't understand is why `null` is printed in this first case but not in other cases (like the second code snippet).

```
public class Case1{

    static String str;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

\\Code prints 'null' without quotes
```

```
public class Case2{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String a[][] = { {}, null };
        System.out.println(a[1][0]);
    }
}

\\Code throws nullPointerException
```

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At `a[1]` an array is expected - and since the array is `null`, a NullPointerException is thrown, because you can't get the 0-th element from `null`.

Comment: `System.out.println` explicitly handles the null case by printing the string `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second example what you are doing is to access the first value of an nonexistent array:

```
String a[][] = { {}, null };
```

So a[1] is the null value, and there is no [0] of that null.

Answer (score 4):

In your example you are trying to access value on the null.

Look at the following code

```
 String a[][] = { {}, null };
 System.out.println(a[1]);
```

it will print

```
null
```

and when you try to access the 0th element on the null, it throw nullpointer expections because you are try to access a element on **null**

```
String a[][] = { {}, null };
System.out.println(a[1][0]);
```

it will output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 2):

In case1, You are just printing string and no value is assigned there, So by default null is printed. You do not perform any operation with that string to throw NullPointerException there. Hence It doesn't throw any exceptions.

In case2, You assign null value to string Array and  tries to get with index so with null object. Hence you got nullPointerException.

if you change case2 with following code you will get null there too.

```
public class Case2{

public static void main(String[] args){

    String a[][] = new String[2][2];
    a[1][0] = null;
    System.out.println(a[1][0]);
    }
}
```

\Code prints 'null' without quotes